# is there any property for knowing which form is running in background

Tags: c#, winforms

I have three windows forms, I have a button in `form1` and a button in the `form2`,
if the button on `form1` has been clicked, then it shows `form2`:

```
form2 f2 = new form2();
f2.show();
```

The `form1` is still in the background and visible. There is one more button on `form2`. When that button is clicked the same event happen that `form2` is running in background and `form3` shows up. When `form3` is shown I want to hide `form1`.

How can I do that? Is there any property that can help me to know which form is running in behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Application.OpenForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) collection to iterate on your open forms.
Then checking for the name of `Form1` you could try to `Hide` it

```
foreach(Form f in Application.OpenForms)
{
   if(f.Name == "Form1")
   {
      f.Hide();
      break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if your form has Focus

```
bool foc = formX.Focused;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use: `Application.OpenForms`.

Answer (score 1):

`Form2` should fire a custom event when it opens `Form3`.  `Form1` shoudl subscribe to that custom event when it shows `Form2`, and then `Form1` can hide itself in that event handler.

```
public class Form2
{
    public event Action Form3Opened;

    public void Bar
    {
        Form3 other = new Form3();
        Form3Opened();
        other.Show();
    }
}

public class Form1
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        Form2 other = new Form2();
        other.Form3Opened += () => Hide();
        other.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: nice but complicated for my case. thanks for giving knowledge

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use [Application.OpenForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx) property to find a collection of all opened forms of *your* application.

The other solution is could be passing *parent form* parameter like the caller form. 
For example: for `Form2` the parent is `Form1`, for `Form3` the parent id `Form2`